# Have multiple alias for Webapp

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have deployed a application in Apache tomcat. Suppose name of project is abc (or deployed from abc.war).

I access it using url :=> `http://localhost:8080/abc/`

But I want to redirect or have aliases for web app. like

`http://localhost:8080/abc/`
`http://localhost:8080/abc1/`
`http://localhost:8080/abc2/`
`http://localhost:8080/abc3/`

All the above reference to same Web-app. How can I do it and I do not want to copy paste the folder as many times and renaming it.

~Thanks

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721966/how-can-i-map-multiple-contexts-to-the-same-war-file-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is not using a warfile.
Copy all the content into a specified directory (i.e. `\user\abc`) and then you can either configure all the contexts in two ways.

- one xml for every context to map, by putting it into your: `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\Catalina\localhost`. Keep in mind that the name of the xml file will be the mapping of your webapp, but you can redefine it with the `path` attribute inside the xml. In your case you have to produce `abc.xml`, `abc1.xml`, `abc2.xml` and their content should be something like:

  > abc.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Context docBase="\user\abc" path="abc" reloadable="false"/>
  ```

  > abc1.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Context docBase="\user\abc" path="abc1" reloadable="false"/>
  ```
- you can edit directly the `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml` by inserting, inside the `<Host ...>` tag, the contexts definitions, something like this:

  ```
  <Host ...>
      <Context docBase="\user\abc" path="abc" reloadable="false"/>
      <Context docBase="\user\abc" path="abc1" reloadable="false"/>
  </Host>
  ```

If you need to provide database datasource information to a context, just add the tag Resource to the context definition itself (either in an xml file or in server.xml),here you go with a sample:

```
<Context docBase="\user\abc" path="abc" reloadable="false">
    <Resource auth="Container" description="DataSource"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        maxActive="4"
        maxIdle="2"
        maxWait="5000"
        name="jdbc/myJNDIname"
        password="mypass"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID"
        username="myuser"/>
</Context>
```

If you need this last part, just use it, obviously, for every context you like to duplicate.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This won't solve the problem! He'll deploy the app multiple times in an exploded fashion. He requires URL rewrite or Redirect Permanent.

Comment: Yeah sure, in that way the weapp is deployed more than 1 time so you have to evaluate all the efforts occurring in this case.
If it's not a lightweight webapp, or it needs to be a permanent, clean solution, the best way is an Apache managing the contexts in front of the appserver.

Answer (score 0):

> the easiest way is create soft link directory of the app, like this

```sh
ln -s $PWD/abc $PWD/abc1
ln -s $PWD/abc $PWD/abc2
ln -s $PWD/abc $PWD/abc3
```