# ALB to map multiple context path on one common port (tomcat)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Currently, we have tomcat based deployments and one Apache server to manage multiple context path on the same port (v-host configuration)

For example,

***ProxyPassMatch /test(.*)               http://127.0.0.1:7077/test$1***

***ProxyPassMatch /test2(.*)               http://127.0.0.1:7077/test2$1***

and so on

Now we are shifting towards ALB of AWS and we want to map all those context paths in ALB as present in Apache configuration file.

We created ***ALB --> Listener on 80 Port --> Target created with a Necessary Instance with port 7077 --> health check is passed***

Listener rule is,

***Context path /test --> Forward to Target Group of 7077 port***

***Context path /test2 --> Forward to Target Group of 7077 port***

But while testing it is showing 502 Bad Gateway when we shut down Apache and to test ALB

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Application Load Balancer cannot rewrite the path going to the target like you can with a typical reverse proxy.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions says:

> The path pattern is used to route requests but does not alter them. For example, if a rule has a path pattern of /img/*, the rule would forward a request for /img/picture.jpg to the specified target group as a request for /img/picture.jpg.

Tomcat specific:

Perhaps you can have the tomcat app listen on multiple paths with configuration in `context.xml` or `server.xml`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721966/how-can-i-map-multiple-contexts-to-the-same-war-file-in-tomcat) has some suggestions, but it seems if you have multiple contexts, the app will run twice and take twice the memory.